# Convert Decimal to Ascii?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

this is how to convert decimal to Ascii, but i have decimal in defferent format, and i want ot convert it to ascii.

```
Public Shared Function DecimalToASCII(dec As String) As String
    Dim ascii As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To dec.Length - 1 Step 3
        ascii += CChar(ChrW(Convert.ToByte(dec.Substring(i, 3))))
    Next

    Return ascii
End Function
```

EX:

This is in Decimal and i want ot input it in textbox1.text:
"912,697,583,1065,261"
and i want to do operation to each group of numbers between comma and then convert it to Ascii???

Comment: It is a one-liner: Return Val(dec).ToString("N0")

Comment: This is in Decimal and i want ot input it in textbox1.text: ' "912,697,583,1065,261" '
and i want to do operation to each group of numbers between comma and then convert it to Ascii???
@Hans Passant

Comment: Yes, that's what that one liner does.  Only two things you can do wrong, not trying it or not telling us what went wrong.

Comment: sorry, but i am trying to do some operation of each group of numbers between comma and then convert it to Ascii??? 
'
            Dim rr As String = TextBox10.Text
            rr = Val(rr).ToString("N0")
            TextBox11.Text = rr

'
I want the result like this:
Input: 912,697,583,1065,261
operation = 912^3 mod 1073,697^3 mod 1073,583^3 mod 1073,1065^3 mod 1073,261^3 mod 1073
output: Ascii code of each group of numbers between comma.

Comment: could you help me? @HansPassant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the string into groups, you can just use the `Split` command. Your code is a long winded way of doing this - although it will fall over when it tries to deal with the four digit number.

Create a string array with no predefined number of elements like this -

```
Dim myArray()
```

Populate it with this code

myArray = Split (dec,",")

So now, using your input example, your ascii **string** array contains this data

myArray (0) = "912"

myArray (1) = "697"

myArray (2) = "583"

myArray (3) = "1065"

myArray (4) = "261"

If you want to have numbers that you can use in arithmetic operations, use this code instead. The function assumes that you're using integers, but if you want to use another type, just change all the occurrences of `Integer` to the type you want to handle, and change the `CInt` function to CDbl or cSng.

```
Public Shared Function DecimalToASCII(dec As String) As Integer()
    'create an array of strings
    Dim ascii() As String

    'split each group into the array
    ascii = Split(dec, ",")

    'declare numbers array that is the same size as the ascii array
    Dim numbers(ascii.GetUpperBound(0)) As Integer

    'convert the array of strings to an array of numbers
    For i As Integer = 0 To ascii.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
        numbers(i) = CInt(ascii(i))
    Next

    'return an array of numbers containing each group
    Return numbers
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
Dim dec As String = "912,697,583,1065,261"
Dim MyNumbersArray() As Integer = DecimalToASCII(dec)
```

With this code, you will have an array of **Integers** like this

MyNumbersArray(0) = 912

MyNumbersArray(1) = 697

MyNumbersArray(2) = 583

MyNumbersArray(3) = 1065

MyNumbersArray(4) = 261

Now you can perform whatever math you want using the array elements.